# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in bindValue

Tags: php

```
if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
if (isset($_POST['title'], $_POST['content'])) {
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $content = $_POST['content'];

    if (empty($title) or empty($content)) {
        $error = 'All fields are required!';
    } else {
        $query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO articles (atricle_title, atricle_text, atricle_timestamp) VALUES (?, ?, ?)")

        $query->bindValue(1, $title); //error is here
        $query->bindValue(2, $content);
        $query->bindValue(3, time());

        $query->execute();

        header(Location: index.php);
}
```

Someone knows what's the problem here?.
The code itself is more then that, but this is to only relevent part.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO articles (atricle_title, atricle_text, atricle_timestamp) VALUES (?, ?, ?)")
```

in this line, the `;` is missing

This line is wrong too:

```
header(Location: index.php);
```

It has to look like this:

```
header("location: index.php");
```

Answer (score 1):

Missed ; at the end of below line,that's why it's showing error on next line when you are trying to bind value. 
$query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO articles (atricle_title, atricle_text, atricle_timestamp) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

and also header(Location: index.php); needs to make parameter as string into header function.

Please try it and me know if any issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because PHP assumes that the line containing the query hasn't ended, and the next character then violates the syntax rule.
Add semi colon `;` to the query line.

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO articles (atricle_title, atricle_text, atricle_timestamp) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed a **`;`** in the **`PDO`** statement and **`quotes`** on the **`header()`**.

```
<?php

if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
if (isset($_POST['title'], $_POST['content'])) {
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $content = $_POST['content'];

    if (empty($title) or empty($content)) {
        $error = 'All fields are required!';
    } else {
        $query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO articles (atricle_title, atricle_text, atricle_timestamp) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

        $query->bindValue(1, $title); //error is here
        $query->bindValue(2, $content);
        $query->bindValue(3, time());

        $query->execute();

        header("Location: index.php");
}
```